# Error al instalar plugins wordpress local

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un enorme problema espero puedan ayudarme, hace poco instale wordpress en manera local osea localhost, y no e podido hacer que se conecte a internet de ninguna manera, por ejemplo al abrir la sección añadir plugins me da la siguiente advertencia.

```
Warning: Ha sucedido un error inesperado. Puede que algo vaya mal con WordPress.org o la configuración de este servidor. Si sigues teniendo problemas, por favor, prueba en los foros de soporte. (WordPress no pudo establecer una conexión segura con WordPress.org. Por favor, contacta con el administrador de tu servidor.) in wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 180

Ha sucedido un error inesperado. Puede que algo vaya mal con WordPress.org o la configuración de este servidor. Si sigues teniendo problemas, por favor, prueba en los foros de soporte.
```

En El caso de los themen me da el mismo error solo que me manda a themen-install.php y si quiero actualizar el mismo error pero update.php. 
ya desactive la carga vía FTP, puedo instalar plguins descargando el .zip y subiéndolo a wordpress o descomprimiendo en la carpeta. y funcionan bien. pero me interesa solventar eso espero puedan ayudarme aquí les dejo la información de mi servidor.

```
== Server Environment ==
    Operating System: Linux
    Software: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
    MySQL version: (Ubuntu) v5.7.28
    PHP Version: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
    PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
    PHP Max Post Size: 50M
    GD Installed: Yes
    ZIP Installed: Yes
    Write Permissions: All right
    Elementor Library: Connected

== WordPress Environment ==
    Version: 5.2.4
    Site URL: http://192.168.1.10/perez
    Home URL: http://192.168.1.10/perez
    WP Multisite: No
    Max Upload Size: 50 MB
    Memory limit: 256M
    Permalink Structure: /%category%/%postname%/
    Language: es-VE
    Timezone: America/Caracas
    Debug Mode: Active

== Theme ==
    Name: Hestia
    Version: 2.5.4
    Author: ThemeIsle
    Child Theme: No

== User ==
    Role: administrator
    WP Profile lang: es_VE
    User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
========
```

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo, dices que instalaste Wordpress de forma local y que quieres que se conecte a internet ¿? ¿Para qué quieres que se conecte a internet?

Comment: El sistema sera utilizado para envio de correos, comentarios y notificaciones de manera intranet pero con acceso a internet, y la razon principal es para poder instalar y actualizar plugins y otros cosa que solo puedo hacer manualmente pero no es la idea.

Comment: Ahora por tu preguntan yo pregunto no exite manera de resolver ese error??? tengo ya un mes en busquedad y hasta ahora solo me han dicho que me comunique con el servidor. pero el servidor soy yo. y no se como solucionarlo asi como tambien otro problemas es lo del localhost el servidor no tiene ip estatica y no tendra. no puedo crear un virtual host ya que no tengo acceso a todos los equipos para configurarlos por lo tanto no se como decirle a wordpress que se limite a la carpeta y no al servidor por ejemplo que habra si es 192.168.1.10/wordpress o localhost/wordpress o 10.40.1.19/wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo ya lo solvente en el archivo HOST coloque la DNS de Wordpress actualizada. no la coloco aquí por que se que puede cambiar pero si alguien tiene el mismo problema la solución es colocar la DNS actual de wordpress.org en el archivo HOST

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/200906)

Comment: Esto es solo informar que ya lo resolvi,, osea encontre la solucion

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregando la siguiente linea en wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Comment: eso fue lo primero que hice antes de hacer este post